# Looking for a program similar to httrack

Tags: linux, software-rec, httrack

I want to find a program that I can use to generate a website backup for offline browsing. I tried Httrack, but it doesn't seem to have scheduling options.

Scheduling is critical for me. I need to download a website on a daily basis.

Is there an alternative program that can do scheduling, along with the capabilities of httrack?

It also has to be free and has to work on linux. Red Hat, to be exact.

Comment: Scheduling is handled by your OS, and applications are not expected to (badly) try to duplicate this functionality. In Unix/Linux, use cron (crontab). In Windows use the Task Scheduler. In Mac use launchd or cron.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`wget` can be used like `httrack`. So if you combine it with `cron` you should be able to address your needs.

Manual should be helpful.

Comment: Currently making progress working with wget and cron. Having trouble downloading the whole website, though. Still, this was useful information, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know this program, but I can recommend you a website I use for finding alternatives for programs and it helped me many times (e.g. finding free programs with the same functionality as the commercial ones etc.)

http://alternativeto.net/software/httrack/

Notice that you website users can "like" programs and then you can sort alternatives according to how many "likes" they've got.
Enjoy.

Comment: That'd theoretically answer the question. You should however mention a few alternatives *here* and only provide the link to `alternativeto.net` for future reference.